# AJAX Call Results In 301 Error

Tags: jquery, ajax, http-status-code-301

I'm making what I think is a fairly straight forward AJAX call using jQuery like this:

jQuery('#picks').load('site/templates/snippetServer.php');

But I'm getting a 301 error back from the server:

GET http://www.brp.dev/site/templates/snippetServer.php    301 Moved Permanently    1ms

What must I change in the jQuery call to fix that?

Bob

Comment: Did you check the snippetServer.php header() ?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. How do I check the snippetServer.php header()?

Comment: Please paste the code for snippetServer.php

Comment: @pvnarula This is all that's there:

<?php

 if(param('snippet')) {
  snippet(param('snippet'));
  exit();
 }

?>